# Drawing with repetition

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I thought I was fairly good at combinatorics, but this puzzle is giving me some trouble!

I have a bag with $N$ balls. I pick one at random, mark it and put it back inside the bag. I repeat this operation $D$ times. What is the probability that I will end up with exactly $C$ clean balls?

Comment: This is closely related to a generalized [birthday problem](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=birthday): $N$ would be days of the year, the $D$ independent "markings" would be draws from a population of people, and the chance of $C$ "clean" balls is the chance that among those $D$ people there are $N-C$ unique birthdays.  As an answer, do you seek a closed formula, an efficient algorithm, or an asymptotic formula (in $N$ or $D$)?

Comment: I'm looking for a closed formula. I will look into the birthday problem, I didn't notice they are related.

Comment: @whuber, in what sense are the clean balls analogous to $N-C$ unique birthdays? Wouldn't they correspond to the days of the year without any birthday?

Comment: I understand "clean" to mean "unmarked."  By analogy, "marked" = "birthday."  You ask for the chance to come up with exactly $N-C$ marked balls.  The analogy interprets this as $N-C$ unique birthdays.  The "clean" balls correspond to days without birthdays in the sample.

Comment: Oh yes, you are correct, I had flipped $C$ and $N-C$ in my head. However, as the number of marks does not matter, the birthdays do not need to be unique, do you agree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this beautiful web page with precisely the information that I was looking for: [Birthday Problem at the university of Alabama in Huntsville](http://www.randomservices.org/random/urn/Birthday.html#General).

Following the derivation in Eq (13) therein, the number of possible $D$-samples from a population of $N$ balls, that exclude exactly $C$ of them is
$$
\#\{\# excluded=C\} = {N\choose C}\sum_{k=0}^{N-C}(-1)^k{N-C\choose k}(N-C-k)^D.
$$

Below, we evaluate the sum analytically. So the probability of ending up with exactly $C$ clean (unmarked) balls is the ratio of $\#\{\# excluded=C\}$ to the total number of possible samples:

$$
P_C = \frac{\#\{\# excluded=C\}}{N^D}=N^{-D} (N-C)! \binom{N}{C}\mathcal{S}_D^{(N-C)},
$$
where $\mathcal{S}_D^{(N-C)}$ is the Stirling number of the second kind.

Comment: +1 This of course is an application of the Principle of Inclusion-Exclusion.  You can alternatively begin with the easily-obtained recursion and use standard methods (of generating functions and solving differential equations) to obtain the second formula directly.

Answer (score 1):

You may use the recurrent formula:

$p(D+1,C) = p(D,C){N-C \over N} + p(D,C+1){C+1 \over N}$

$p(0,C) = \cases{1,&if C=N\\0,&otherwise}$